# What kinds of set functions are Jordan inner and outer measures?

Tags: real-analysis

For a bounded subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, its inner Jordan measure is defined as
$$
    m_*(B)=\sup_{S\subset B} m (S)
$$
and its outer Jordan measure as
$$
    m^*(B)=\inf_{S\supset B} m (S)
$$
where the infimum and supremum are taken over simple sets $S$ and $m$ is the volume function of simple sets. The definitions are from  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure).

I am considering this question: are Jordan inner and outer measures   [outer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure) and [inner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_measure) measures respectively?

- Jordan inner measure  satisfies null at empty set and superadditivity, but can it fail "Limits of decreasing towers" and "Infinity must be approached"?
- Jordan outer measure satisfies null at empty set and monotonicity, but can it fail [the countable subadditivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions)?

If they are not outer and inner measures, what kinds of set functions are they?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you know $m^*(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1])$ and $m^*(\{x\})$ ... and perhaps these will answer one of your questions ???

Comment: @GEdgar: $ m^∗(\{x\}) = 0$ because we can choose an arbitrarily small interval containing $x$? $m^∗(Q\cap [0,1]) = 0$ because for any $\epsilon >0$, we can always find finitely many intervals containing $Q\cap [0,1]$, and the volume of their union is smaller than $\epsilon$? So $m^∗(Q\cap [0,1]) = 0 = \sum_{x \in Q\cap [0,1]} m^∗(\{x\})$. It isn't a counterexample, and does it answer the question for outer measure?

Comment: Your answer for $m^*(\{x\})$ is correct.  Your answer for the other one is not.

Comment: @GEdgar: I see, $m^∗(Q∩[0,1]) = 1$. If I am correct, how about the question for inner measure?